# How to translate Javascript Class to ScalaJS

Tags: javascript, scala, scala.js

I have this simple Javascript Code:

```
import Modeler from 'bpmn-js/lib/Modeler';

import diagramXML from './diagram.bpmn';

const modeler = new Modeler({
  container: '#canvas'
});

modeler.importXML(diagramXML);
```

This displays a diagram when opening in the browser.

I want to do this in **ScalaJS** but I miss something.

Here is my code:

```
@JSImport("resources/diagram.bpmn", JSImport.Default)
@js.native
object DiagramXML extends js.Object

object Main {

  @JSExportTopLevel("main")
  def main(): Unit = {
    val modeler = new Modeler(js.Object(
      "container" -> "#canvas"
    ))

   modeler.importXML(DiagramXML.toString)
 }
}
```

Here is my Facade for the `Modeler`:

```scala
@js.native
@JSImport("bpmn-js/lib/Modeler", "Modeler")
class BpmnJS(options: js.Object) extends js.Object {

  def importXML(xml: String): js.Promise[Any] = js.native

}
```

When I debug, the xml is loaded correctly. All that is missing, is that it is rendered correctly in the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can identify two issues in your translation. The first one is the `import` of `bpmn-js`. The JS import is

```js
import Modeler from 'bpmn-js/lib/Modeler';
```

which should be translated to

```scala
@JSImport("bpmn-js/lib/Modeler", JSImport.Default)
```

according to [the documentation on translating `import` into `@JSImport`](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/facade-types.html#translating-es-imports-to-scalajs-jsimport).

The other issue is more subtle. In your invocation of `new Modeler`, you have

```scala
js.Object(
  "container" -> "#canvas"
)
```

which (perhaps unfortunately) compiles but doesn't do what you think it does. It creates a Scala tuple of the two strings, which is passed to the JavaScript function `Object(...)` which will in fact return it as is (because the Scala tuple is already an object).

What you wanted was a JavaScript object with a field `container`, which you can write as

```scala
new js.Object {
  val container = "#canvas"
}
```

An even better way to do this would be to make the options object statically typed in the facade:

```scala
class BpmnJS(options: BpmnJSOptions) extends js.Object {
  ..
}

trait BpmnJSOptions extends js.Object {
  var container: js.UndefOr[String] = js.undefined
}
```

That way, you'll be able to call it as

```scala
new BpmnJS(new BpmnJSOptions {
  container = "#canvas"
})
```

Comment: thanks that work - interesting is that it only worked when using your proposed `BpmnJSOptions`.